# Nginx: Need explanation of $request_time

Tags: http, nginx, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a server with **nginx** and I am sending an API response to a client.

I am logging my `$request_time` in the logs. I need to know if `$request_time` logs the time taken for processing at my server and sending the request to the client or does it log the time when the response is received by the client.

Does anything change based on weather the connection is keep-alive or not?

I read the docs which said:

```
According to nginx doc value of $request_time variable (available only at logging) will be compute when all data have been send and connection have been closed (by all upstreams and proxy also). And only then info is appended to log.
```

But the connection being closed part is not explained there.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html):

> `$request_time`
>
> request processing time in seconds with a milliseconds
>   resolution; time elapsed between the first bytes were read from the
>   client and the log write after the last bytes were sent to the client

I.e. it times up until all data has been sent to the client, but not including the time it takes for the client to receive it.

Comment: Is there suggestion how to find time for client to receive response?

Comment: That documentation is very misleading, the main developer said here https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,288938,288955#msg-288955 "... to sending the last byte of the response to the socket buffer. Note the difference: not deliverying the last byte to the user, but sending the response to the socket buffer"

And follow up question: how to actually see the time it took to reach client was left unanswered